# Apps Script - Loop until no data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write the below function to auto populate google forms from google sheets. It works for the first line, but I can't get it to loop.

```
function auto_data_entry() {


var formURL="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSfdBERX06DYzZpgAT6KheTAG0DghH5_5kxw-sLkyQJQ/formResponse"

var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var wrkSht = wrkBk.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var lastRow = wrkSht.getLastRow();

for (var i=2; i <=lastRow; i++) {
var column1 = wrkSht.getRange("A2").getValue();
var column2 = wrkSht.getRange("B2").getValue();
var column3 = wrkSht.getRange("C2").getValue();
var column4 = wrkSht.getRange("D2").getValue();

var datamap={"entry.1856088635":column1,
"entry.40472690":column2,
"entry.40472690":column3,
"entry.108043170":column4};

var options = {
  "method": "post",
  "payload": datamap
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch(formURL, options);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Loop all data

```
function auto_data_entry() {
  const formURL = "https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSfdBERX06DYzZpgAT6KheTAG0DghH5_5kxw-sLkyQJQ/formResponse"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
  let datamap = {"entry.1856088635": r[0],"entry.40472690": r[1],"entry.40472690": r[2],"entry.108043170": r[3]};
  var options = {"method": "post","payload": datamap};
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(formURL, options);
  });
}
```